# what does these swift codes mean?

Tags: swift

```
func textView(textView:UITextView,shouldChangeTextInRange
           rang:NSRange,replacementText text:String)->Bool{
        if(text == "\n"){
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

what  (`return false && return true`  ) mean?

Comment: It means if a certain condition is true return false, else return true

Comment: but it does not include else

Comment: I'm just saying that as a fact, it doesn't explicitly state that but that's the control flow

Comment: edit your code please.

Comment: You should try to format your example so it's more readable and clear. You'll get more responses.

Comment: @wuyibin - No `else` is needed. If the `if` succeeds, it encounters the `return false` and the function exits immediately and it never gets to the `return true` line. It's functionally equivalent to having the `else { return false }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am just step into this world. And thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If a certain condition is true, it return false, else return true. You don't need `else` here because `return` exit the function immediately, all code after return won't be executed.

Comment: Instead of answering, this should be a comment because the answer of the question is quite straightforward and only requires a comment

Comment: @AndrewL `this should be a comment because the answer of the question is quite straightforward and only requires a comment` Nonsense. Comments are for commenting, answers are for answering.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from function name `shouldChangeTextInRange`, that it is asking whether it should change character in textfield or not, so it returns a boolean accordingly... So if a certain condition met like `text == "\n"` i.e., if value of `text` variable is `\n` it should resign keyboard and should not change character in field. Otherwise anything typed to the textfield will be appear in the control.